# Angular - Dynamically add set of fields on pressing tab

Tags: angular, loops, dynamic-programming, textfield

I'm working in Angular 7.
What is currently being done is,

User can enter Quantity (1,2,3 etc) and  the number of dynamic fields will be arranged as per quantity.

**What I want to achieve is to remove the quantity field and get 1 set of field by default and as the field starts filing when the user is on the last field and presses "tab button" the next set of dynamic fields is automatically generated.**

For example:

**Currently what is being done:**

Color:_______

Shape:_______

Enter Quantity: 1

//Set of fields gets repeated 1 time.

Color:_______

Shape:_______

**What I want to achieve:**

Color:_______

Shape:_______ //When I press "tab button" when my input is focusing on shape a new set of fields is generated automatically.

My componenent.ts file:

```
 public myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      FrontEnd: ['',],
      languages: this._fb.array([
          this.initlanguage(),
      ])
  });
  }

   initlanguage() {
        return this._fb.group({
            color: [''],
            shape: ['']
        });
    }

    qty:number;
    newqty:number;
    addLanguage() {
      for(this.qty=0;this.qty<this.newqty;this.qty++){
      const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['languages'];
      control.push(this.initlanguage());
      }
  }

  removeLanguage(i: number) {
      const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['languages'];
      control.removeAt(i);
  }
```

My component.html file:

```
        <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
          <div formArrayName="languages">
            <div *ngFor="let language of myForm.controls.languages.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="nc-mobile pull-right" *ngIf="myForm.controls.languages.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeLanguage(i)"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                  <label>Color</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="color">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                  <label>Shape</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="shape">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      <input placeholder="Enter Quantity here" [(ngModel)]="newqty"/> 

          <div class="margin-20">
            <a (click)="addLanguage()" style="cursor: default">
              Add another Fieldset +
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="margin-20">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

**Summary:
Generate dynamic set of fields when user presses tab on the last selected input field.**

Comment: By memory, i should use the keydown event : 
`<input (keydown.tab)="customMethod()" >` and in your custom method you do what you need.